# how can i display google nearbyplace api images response in listview?

Tags: android, json

I am using json volley to for getting information from google api.I know how to display text in listview but dont know how to display images because they are in string form i really dont know how to convert that string into image and display in listview . here is my code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
ListView lst_1;
Button btn_one;
String url;
ArrayList<CostumAdapter> contactList;
private ProgressDialog progress;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(activity_main);
    contactList = new ArrayList<>();
    lst_1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lst_1);

    btn_one = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_1);
    btn_one.setOnClickListener(this);

}

public void Progress() {
    progress = new ProgressDialog(this);
    progress.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
    progress.setMessage("Loading");
    progress.show();
}

private void jsonfunction() {
    Progress();
    url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?" +
            "location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&" +
            "radius=500&" +
            "type=restaurant&" +
            "key=AIzaSyAG5Fndg4wPzs81FNv5-Ycl7GDlAdqeIaI" +
            "&sensor=true";

    Log.e("url", url);
    final StringRequest stringrequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.e("response", response);
            try {
                JSONObject jsonobj = new JSONObject(response);
                JSONArray jsonArray = jsonobj.getJSONArray("results");
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                    JSONArray jsonArray2 = object.getJSONArray("photos");
                    for (int a = 0; a < jsonArray2.length(); a++) {
                        JSONObject object2 = jsonArray2.getJSONObject(a);


                        contactList.add(new CostumAdapter(
                                jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("name"),
                                object2.getString("photo_reference")
                        ));
                    }
                }

                Log.e("response in a", String.valueOf(contactList));


            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "error in jason", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            function();


        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "error in ErrorListener", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
    singalton.getinstance(MainActivity.this).addtorequestque(stringrequest);

}
 public void function() {
    CustomListAdapter adapter = new CustomListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.custumlistview, contactList);
    lst_1.setAdapter(adapter);
}
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    jsonfunction();
}
```

}

Comment: You can use NetworkImageView of Volly Library for image show.

Comment: please explain your answer in detail

Comment: First you have to create custom list view item with network image view and text in xml. and then load the image using image loader in netwrok image view.

Comment: can you give any example of this type??

Comment: https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-custom-listview-with-images-using-recyclerview-and-volley/

Comment: this link does not give any help

Comment: If this link is not helpful for you, then you can not never learn android.